# web.config rewrite rules issue?

Tags: php, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

I used IIS 7 URL rewrite module 2 to convert my .htaccess file to web.config.

when using the .htaccess on my apache server everything works fine.  However when I use my web.config on my IIS 7 server, everything goes to hell.

I have 3 admin pages : addcharacter.php, deletecharacter.php, editcharacter.php

the code is :

```
    <li><a href='admin/addcharacter' title='Add Character'>Add Character</a></li>
    <li><a href='admin/deletecharacter' title='Delete Character'>Delete Character</a></li>
    <li><a href='admin/editcharacter' title='Edit Character'>Edit Character</a></li>
```

where the problem lies is once i go to the first link:

www.mywebsite/admin/addcharacter  -- the first time works fine

if I switch to another link (regardless of whatever link it is) it appends the admin again

www.mywebsite/admin/admin/destination page

i think it's related to the web.config file since that's the only difference.

here is a portion of my config file:

```
   <rule name="Imported Rule 9">
                    <match url="^logout$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="logout.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 10">
                    <match url="^admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="admin.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 11">
                    <match url="^admin/([A-z][a-z]+)/?$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="admin.php?action={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Those rules don't appear to have anything to do with addcharacter.php, deletecharacter.php, or editcharacter.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your links, not in the rewrite rules. You shouldn't use relative links but absolute links. When you are on `www.mywebsite/admin/addcharacter` and you click a link `admin/anotherpage` the browser will send a request for `www.mywebsite/admin/admin/anotherpage`. That's just how relative links work and there's nothing the server can do about that. You should have the same problem on an Apache server however.

So your links should be:

```
<li><a href='/admin/addcharacter' title='Add Character'>Add Character</a></li>
<li><a href='/admin/deletecharacter' title='Delete Character'>Delete Character</a></li>
<li><a href='/admin/editcharacter' title='Edit Character'>Edit Character</a></li>
```